# c++ GLS numerical integration error: COULD NOT INTEGRATE FUNCTION

Tags: c++, numerical-integration

I'm new to both stackoverflow and C++ programming.

I'm trying to compute the cosmological Mass Variance by numerically integrate the function given by (primordial power spectrum * transfer function * window function). I'm not able to perform the numerical integration between 0 and +infinity of such a function, which is peaked about 0 and then rapidly drops to zero:

i) if I try to apply the gsl_integration_qag() integrator between a very small number (i.e 10^-10) and a big number (i.e. 10^4), then I obtain the error "COULD NOT INTEGRATE FUNCTION";

ii) if I try to apply the gsl_integration_qagiu() integrator with 0 (or a small number) as lower limit, then I obtain the error "BAD INTEGRAND BEHAVIOUR";

This is the link to the GLS library I'm using  https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/integration.html .

All the functions should be well written, as I tried to rewrite the code in Mathematica and I obtain exactly the result I expected (however the project must be written in C++). Could someone give me any suggestion about the numerical integration routine?

Thank you in advance for your time,
Filippo

I attach my code:

\\\\\\\ COSMOLOGY.h \\\\\\\\\\

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _COSMOLOGY_H_
#define _COSMOLOGY_H_

#include <math.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>

#define FRACT_FLOAT_ERR (float) 1e-6

/*** COSMOLOGICAL PARAMETERS  ****/
#define OMm (float) 0.308  /* Omega matter - 1 for Einstein-deSitter Universe */
#define OMl (float) 0.692  /* Omega lambda - 0 for Einstein-deSitter Universe */
#define OMb (float) 0.046  /* Omega baryon */
#define OMc (float) 0.258  /* Omega dark matter */
#define OMnu (float) (OMm - OMb - OMc)  /* Omega neutrinos */
#define OMtot (float) (OMm + OMl)
#define hlittle (float) 0.6789
#define SIGMA8 (float) 0.82
#define POWER_INDEX (float) 0.96
#define wl (float) -1

// physical parameters from Eisenstein 1997
#define theta_27 (float) (2.728 / 2.7)  /* theta_2.7 parameter from CMB temperature */
#define z_eq (float) (2.5 * pow(10.0, 4.0) * OMm * pow(hlittle, 2.0) * pow(theta_27, -4.0))  /* matter-radiation equality redshift */
#define f_c (float) (OMc / OMm)
#define f_b (float) (OMb / OMm)
#define f_nu (float) (OMnu / OMm)
#define f_cb (float) ((OMc + OMb) / OMm)
#define f_cnu (float) ((OMc + OMnu) / OMm)
#define f_bnu (float) ((OMnu + OMb) / OMm)
#define p_c (float) ((5.0 - sqrt(1.0 + 24.0 * f_c)) / 4.0)
#define p_cb (float) ((5.0 - sqrt(1.0 + 24.0 * f_cb)) / 4.0)
#define N_nu (float) 3.0
#define b_1 (float) (0.313 * pow(OMm, -0.419) * pow(hlittle, (-2.0 * 0.419)) * (1.0 + 0.607 * pow(OMm, 0.674) * pow(hlittle, (2.0 * 0.674))))
#define b_2 (float) (0.238 * pow(OMm, 0.223) * pow(hlittle, (2.0 * 0.223)))
#define z_drag (float) (1291.0 * pow(OMm, 0.251) * pow(hlittle, (2 * 0.251)) * (1.0 + b_1 * pow(OMb, b_2) * pow(hlittle, (2.0 * b_2))) / (1.0 + 0.659 * pow(OMm, 0.828) * pow(hlittle, (2.0 * 0.828))))
#define y_drag (float) ((1.0 + z_eq) / (1.0 + z_drag))
#define alpha_nu_1 (float) ((f_c / f_cb) * (5.0 - 2.0 * (p_c + p_cb)) / (5.0 - 4.0 * p_cb))
#define alpha_nu_2 (float) ((1.0 - 0.553 * f_bnu + 0.126 * pow(f_bnu, 3.0)) / (1.0 - 0.193 * sqrt(f_nu * N_nu) + 0.169 * f_nu * pow(N_nu, 0.2)))
#define alpha_nu_3 (float) (pow((1.0 + y_drag), (p_cb - p_c)) * (1.0 + 0.5 * (p_c - p_cb) / (1.0 + y_drag) * (1.0 + 1.0 / ((3.0 - 4.0 * p_c) * (7.0 - 4.0 * p_cb)))))
#define alpha_nu_tot (float) (alpha_nu_1 * alpha_nu_2 * alpha_nu_3)
#define sound_horizon (float) ((44.5 * logf(9.83 / OMm / pow(hlittle, 2.0))) / sqrt(1.0 + 10 * pow(OMb, 0.75) * pow(hlittle, (2.0 * 0.75)))) /* * pow(10.0, 6.0)) - defined in Mpc units */
#define beta_c (float) (1 / (1.0 - 0.949 * f_bnu))

#endif
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\ THE MAIN CODE \\\\\\\\\\\

```
// incude the LCDM cosmology
#include "COSMOLOGY.h"
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

// define pi greco
#define pi_greco (float) 3.141593
#define e_nepero (float) 2,71828


// define the function to have equality with some precision, instead of =
int isequal(float a, float b) {
if (fabs((a - b)) <= fabs(a * FRACT_FLOAT_ERR))
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// define the top hat window function
float th_window_function(float k, float R) {
return 4.0 * pi_greco * pow(R, 3.0) * (sin(k * R) / (pow(k, 3.0) * pow(R, 3.0)) - cos(k * R) / (pow(k, 2.0) * pow(R, 2.0)));
}
// define the effective volume of the top hat window function
float th_effective_volume(float R) {
return 4.0 * pi_greco * pow(R, 3.0) / 3.0;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// define the growth factor (not squared) - eq. 6 and 8 from liddle et al. 1994
// redshift evolution of the matter fraction
float OMm_z(float Z) {
return OMm * pow((1.0 + Z), 3) / (1 - OMm + OMm * pow((1.0 + Z), 3.0));
}
// eq. 6
float g_z(float Z) {
return (5.0 / 2.0) * OMm_z(Z) / (1.0 / 70.0 +
    (209.0 / 140.0) * OMm_z(Z) -
    OMm_z(Z) * OMm_z(Z) / 140.0 +
    pow(OMm_z(Z), (4.0 / 7.0)));
}
// eq. 8
float growth_factor(float Z) {
// Einstein-de-Sitter
if (isequal(OMm, 1) && isequal(OMtot, OMm)) {
    return 1 / (1.0 + Z);
}
//Lambda CMD
if (isequal(OMtot, OMm + OMl) && isequal(OMtot, 1)) {
    return g_z(Z) / g_z(0.0) / (1.0 + Z);
}
fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: no growth function for this cosmology! returning -1\n");
return -1;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// define the growth factor (not squared) D1 from Eisenstein 1997
// redshift evolution of the matter fraction
float OMl_z(float Z) {
return OMl / (OMm * pow((1.0 + Z), 3.0) + OMl);
}

// D1 from eq. 10
float D_1_growth(float Z) {
return (1.0 + z_eq) / (1.0 + Z) * (5.0 / 2.0) * OMm_z(Z) / (pow(OMm_z(Z), (4.0 / 7.0)) - OMl_z(Z) + (1.0 + OMm_z(Z) / 2.0) * (1.0 + OMl_z(Z) / 70.0));
}


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// define the comoving wavenumber k normalized to the scale that crosses the horizon at matter-radiation equality - eq. 5 from Eisenstein 1997
float q_eq(float k) {
return k /*/ pow(10.0, -6.0)*/ * pow(theta_27, 2.0) / (OMm * hlittle * hlittle);
}
// define the free-streaming epoch - eq. 14 from Eisenstein 1997
float y_fs(float k) {
return 17.2 * f_nu * (1.0 + 0.488 * pow(f_nu, -(7.0 / 6.0))) * pow((N_nu * q_eq(k) / f_nu), 2.0);
}
// define the growth factor in the free-streaming epoch - eq. 13 from Eisenstein 1997
float D_cbnu(float Z, float k) {
return pow((pow(f_cb, (0.7 / p_cb)) + pow((D_1_growth(Z) / (1.0 + y_fs(k))), 0.7)), (p_cb / 0.7)) * pow(D_1_growth(Z), (1.0 - p_cb));
}
// define the suppression scale - eq. 16 from Eisenstein 1997
float gamma_eff(float k) {
return OMm * pow(hlittle, 2.0) * (sqrt(alpha_nu_tot) + (1.0 - sqrt(alpha_nu_tot)) / (1.0 + pow((0.43 * k * sound_horizon), 4.0)));
}
// define the suppression wavenumber - eq. 17 from Eisenstein 1997
float q_eff(float k) {
return k * pow(theta_27, 2.0) / (gamma_eff(k))/* * pow(10.0, -6.0))*/;
}
// define eq. 19 from Eisenstein 1997
float L_transfer(float k) {
return logf((e_nepero + 1.84 * beta_c * sqrt(alpha_nu_tot) * q_eff(k)));
}
// define eq. 20 from Eisenstein 1997
float C_transfer(float k) {
return 14.4 + 325.0 / (1.0 + 60.5 * pow(q_eff(k), 1.08));
}
// define eq. 18 from Eisenstein 1997
float T_sup(float k) {
return L_transfer(k) / (L_transfer(k) + C_transfer(k) * pow(q_eff(k), 2.0));
}
// define eq. 23 from Eisenstein 1997
float q_nu(float k) {
return 3.92 * q_eq(k) * sqrt(N_nu / f_nu);
}
// define eq. 22 from Eisenstein 1997
float B_correction(float k) {
return 1.0 + (1.24 * pow(f_nu, 0.64) * pow(N_nu, (0.3 + 0.6 * f_nu))) / (pow(q_nu(k), -1.6) + pow(q_nu(k), 0.8));
}
// define the master transfer function - eq. 24 from Eisenstein 1997
float T_master(float k) {
return T_sup(k) * B_correction(k);
}
// define the TRANSFER FUNCTION - eq. 7 from Eisenstein 1997
float transfer_function(float Z, float k) {
return T_master(k) * D_cbnu(Z, k) / D_1_growth(Z);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// define the matter power spectrum in the fourier space
float non_normalized_sigma2_k(float Z, float k) {
return pow(k, POWER_INDEX) * pow(transfer_function(Z, k), 2.0) * pow(growth_factor(Z), 2.0);
}
// define the real volume
float real_volume(float R) {
return 4.0 * pi_greco * pow(R, 3.0) / 3.0;
}
//define the variance in the Fourier space
float non_normalized_Delta2_k(float Z, float k, float R) {
return 1.0 / (2 * pow(pi_greco, 2.0)/* * real_volume(R)*/) * pow(k, 3.0) * non_normalized_sigma2_k(Z, k);
}
// define function to be integrated
double integrand_f(double k, void* params) {
float Z = *(float*)params;
float R = *(float*)params;
return (1e30) * non_normalized_Delta2_k(Z, k, R) * pow(th_window_function(k, R), 2.0) / k / pow(th_effective_volume(R), 2.0);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// define the critical treshold for the spherical collapse model
float delta_crit(float Z) {
return 1.686 / growth_factor(Z);
}





int main(void) {

double result_f, error_f, lower_limit, upper_limit;
float Z, R, R_FACTOR;
lower_limit = 1.0e-15/*logf(0.01)*/;
upper_limit = 1e5/*logf(1e7)*/;
Z = 0.0;
R_FACTOR = 1.01;
R = 1e-6;

gsl_integration_workspace* w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(1000);
gsl_function F;
F.function = &integrand_f;
F.params = &Z, & R;

std::ofstream myfile1;
myfile1.open("integration_sigma2M.dat");  //cambia nome
while (R < 0.5) {
    gsl_integration_qag(&F, lower_limit, upper_limit, 0.0/*errore assoluto*/, 1e-3/*errore relativo*/, 1000/*size_t limit*/, 6, w, &result_f, &error_f);

    printf("%f\t%f\t%f\n", R, result_f, error_f);

    myfile1 << R << "\t" << result_f << "\t" << error_f << "\n";

    R = (1 + R) * R_FACTOR - 1;
}
myfile1.close();

gsl_integration_workspace_free(w);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use constants to the maximal available precision, there are sources with billions of digits of pi, 20 should be sufficient here, and the Napier/Euler number is easy to calculate in any precision. Do care about dots and commas. /// Also, you are violating the MWE principle. If you are asking about the correct usage of integration routines, or how to treat singularities, choose a simple model that still shows the same errors. It may turn out that the problem is more of a mathematical or physical nature, then other sides may be more on-topic.

Comment: Thank you @LutzLehmann for your response! I will use more precise values of the constants. Could you please explain me what is MWE principle and why I'm violating it? I tried to google it, but I have not been able to find any clear explanation

Comment: MWE means minimal working example, in the sense that it exhibits the same problem as the actual code. You have lots of model-specific functions to construct the integrand, but can you find a simple function with about the same general characteristics that produces the same error message? Can you isolate the error to just one call of the integrating function?